# Debug graphic program with optirun in netbeans (ubuntu)

Tags: netbeans

I'm trying to debug a program that uses optirun (bumblebee). Its easy to start it in "release" mode, by editing the project properties, setting Run -> Rund cmmand to /usr/bin/optirun "${OUTPUT_PATH}"

The problem comes when I need to debug. Editing project properties -> Debug -> Debug command to /usr/bin/optirun gdb "${OUTPUT_PATH}" the program starts but as an interactive session in netbeans terminal.

If I use the command "/usr/bin/optirun gdb" then program starts correctly but in any case stops in breakpoints.

Any idea is wellcome.

Thanks in advance